# Wordpress : How to hide page depend on time in php

Tags: php

I'm looking to hide some page of a website between 10 AM AND 20 PM each day

I add the code below on the file function.php

```
<?php 
if (date('H')>10 && date('H')<20{echo 'url page';}
?>
```

This code breaks the website. I'm looking for the correct code to add.

Comment: You are missing a `)` from your `if` statement (after `<20`).

Answer (score 0):

Besides syntax errors mentioned in comments, I guess you need to check whether it is the particular page you need to lock down, so you won't do that to the entire site. If that page is some WordPress post, you can block access by post ID, like this:

```php
function blockAccessFromPost($post) {
  $post_id = $post->ID;
  $hours = intval(date('H'));

  if ($hours >= 9 && $hours < 20 && $post_id === 1123) {
    echo 'Please wait...';
    exit; // exit is required so no further code is executed.
  }
}
add_action('the_post', 'blockAccessFromPost');
```

In case if you don't know where to find the post/page id, here's the [article](https://www.competethemes.com/blog/find-page-id/).

*The previous version of the answer was wrong, because it was unable to get access to the post data right away, WordPress was not initalized.  `the_post` hook helps to execute the code in the moment when current post data has just loaded.*

Comment: I use this, (changing hours for try), the website work but the post is this visible.

```<?php 

$post_id = get_post()->ID;
$hours = intval(date('H'));

if ($hours >= 9 && $hours < 20 && $post_id ===1123) {
  echo 'Please wait...';
  exit; // exit is required so no further code is executed.
}
?>```

Comment: I got it, I'll come up with updated answer in a minute.

Comment: Try it now, Alessandro

Comment: Make sure the post id is correct, also there could be a problem with the time on your server (different timezone?). Also place this code at the beginning of ```functions.php``` so it will execute for sure. If that won't work, try to ```echo``` some text inside the function ```blockAccessFromPost()``` to make sure that it is executed.

Comment: Make ```echo $post->ID;``` inside this function, compare to the post id that you're trying to block, probably it's not the same. There's still a lot of things you can do to get it working.

Comment: The ID is correct, ```echo $post->ID;``` make show the well post ID.  I have set the time zone, this is now ok.  
The post now disapear but at the start and even at the end of the fonctions.php it broke the website. The half is working.

Comment: There's no syntax error in my code, you proved it yourself, when you said that the site is okay earlier. So the problem is somewhere else. Take a look at the log file or error description, it will give you an exact filepath, the line number where error occurs, and the error description which may help you to solve the issue.

Comment: With the last update you give me, the post disapear, I don't said your code didn't worked. There is no error message, is just that the half of the homepage and other page was disappear.  The footer/widgets disappear too. And when I take off the code it come back to normal.

Comment: Oh well, try to add `return $post;` to the end of the function, just before `}`. It may work out well.

Comment: Yes, this really should work, check it out, Alessandro.

Answer (score 0):

Still the same, I really don't know with, your code look perfect. When I use it, the post disappear in the list and I can see wirtten "Please wait...1391". But widget footer etc disappear. 
I post you back the code below to be sure to use it well..

````
function blockAccessFromPost($post) {
  $post_id = $post->ID;
  $hours = intval(date('H'));

  if ($hours >= 9 && $hours < 20 && $post_id === 1391) {
    echo 'Please wait...';
      echo $post->ID;
    exit; // exit is required so no further code is executed.
  }
return $post;}
add_action('the_post', 'blockAccessFromPost');
?>```
````

Comment: Okay, there are no errors, but I think I just didn't get you right. As far as I get now, you see only the message we echoed on this particular post, but you want the entire page, just not to display the content of this post. You can try to use ```$post->post_content = 'your message';``` in the condition block, just remove that ```exit```, ```echo```s and place it there. That way you can change different properties of the post to make it look properly, [see docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post).

Comment: Also I think it will be more helpful for you to address WordPress-related issues to the [WordPress development portal](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) in the future.